# Twitter Bootstrap: Form with an icon inside of it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my form in my navigation to be just like [Flickr.com](http://www.flickr.com/) using Twitter Bootstrap. Right now I use the append ability for the form:

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
  <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>
```

What I've tried so far is to change the design to look like the form input but than I can't use the focus highlight, box shadows and theirs this gap in between them that doesn't feel right. So if I'm trying to do this (like Flickr):

[image: Flickr Form Design]

Than what can I do?

Comment: if possible please share your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does just about what I'm looking for:

http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/stylish-search-form?

Answer (score 0):

create a new css file lets say **custom-bootstrap.css**, and write this style to override bootstraps default style

```
input:focus
{
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=0,MakeShadow=false,ShadowOpacity=0.0);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=0,MakeShadow=false,ShadowOpacity=0.0)";
}
```

NOTE: Make sure to place this css after bootstrap's css so that it can override the default style.

this will do the trick for whole your website theme.

Comment: Thanks, I found this snippet by accident that does what I'm looking for, appreciate the help though. (http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/stylish-search-form?)

Comment: That will do some trick, sure, but also it will prevent you from updating Bootstrap, and you'll have no documentation for your "custom" framework, and if any issue appears you will never know who's responsible. Cheating the library files is never an option, and CSS is easily extensible. Downvoting.

Comment: actually he will need to have same theme throughout his website, but you are right though. Editing the answer..